# HighChart export server can not export static images through the Docker file

Tags: node.js, docker, express, highcharts, server

I am using `OS-Windows 11 Enterprice`, `NodeJS 14.0.0`, `NPM 6.14.4` and `Highchart exprot server 2.1.0`

Trying to generate/export static images through the docker.

Docker File:

```
# Getting image from node

FROM node:carbon

ENV ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE="1"
ENV HIGHCHARTS_USE_STYLED="1"
ENV HIGHCHARTS_USE_MAPS="1"
ENV HIGHCHARTS_USE_GANTT="1"

RUN npm install highcharts-export-server -g --unsafe-perm
RUN npm config set strict-ssl=false
RUN node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/build.js

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

#CMD ls

EXPOSE 3001

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ] 

#ENTRYPOINT ["highcharts-export-server", "--enableServer", "1"]
```

Exporting Highchart image code (developed in NodeJS as API : index.js file name) :

```
const chartExporter = require("highcharts-export-server");
    chartExporter.initPool();    
    let imageB64 = '';  
    chartExporter.export(chartDetails, (err, res) => {
         imageB64 = res.data;             
            response.send(imageB64);
        chartExporter.killPool();
    });
```

I am successfully export/generate the image while manually running index.js in NodeJS.
But facing below error while running through Docker image.

```
Error : phantom worker 5/6/7/8/9 unexpected data - SyntaxError: Expected token ')'
  phantomjs://code/worker.js:658 in loop
```

I am using below Highchart JSON object for generating chart:

```
const chartDetails = {
        type: "jpeg",
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: "pie"
            },
            title: {
                text: "Heading of Chart"
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: "<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}"
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    data: [
                        {
                            name: "a",
                            y: 20
                        },
                        {
                            name: "b",
                            y: 20
                        },
                        {
                            name: "c",
                            y: 50
                        },
                        {
                            name: "d",
                            y: 10
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            exporting: {
                sourceWidth: 200,
                sourceHeight: 200
            }
        }
    };
```

Please let me know for further details.
Thanks in an advance.

Comment: This issue seems to be related to the following threads: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/314 ;
https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/312

Alternatively, you can test the new Export Server which is available on the following branch https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/tree/enhancement/puppeteer (not yet available from npm) . 

Let me know if it helped you with your issue!

Comment: @magdalena Still facing same issue...

Comment: My apologies for the late response. Unfortunately, we don't have an official guide on how to set up an export server with Docker. It is possible that in the future we will publish a tutorial for a new export server based on Puppeteer.
At this time, I can suggest you look at the following article written by another user, which might be helpful in your case: https://medium.com/@sant1/exporting-charts-using-highcharts-export-server-76180dad5317

Comment: @magdalena In that approach server not responded. Executing PowerShell 
command 
$Uri = 'http://localhost:8089';
$Headers = @{'Content-Type', 'application/json'};
$FileContent = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\Users\jbhatt\Desktop\test\test.json');
$Fields = @{'appInfo'='{"name": "test","description": "test"}';'uploadFile'=$FileContent};
$output = "C:\Users\jbhatt\Desktop\test\testchart.png"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -ContentType 'multipart/form-data' -Method Post -Headers $Headers -Body $Fields -OutFile $output;
If possible can you provide me step by step development and execution steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below docker file. Use node:14 image and comment the line `ssl_conf = ssl_sect` in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

```
FROM node:14/15/16/17

ENV ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE="YES"
ENV HIGHCHARTS_VERSION=8.1.2 
ENV HIGHCHARTS_USE_STYLED="YES"
ENV HIGHCHARTS_USE_MAPS="YES"
ENV HIGHCHARTS_USE_GANTT="YES"
ENV HIGHCHARTS_MOMENT="NO"

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY index.js .

RUN sed -i 's/ssl_conf = ssl_sect/#ssl_conf = ssl_sect/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

EXPOSE 3001

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```